# How to Get Custom Slack App Channel ID via Slack API

Tags: apex, slack, slack-app

I'm currently working with the Slack API and facing a specific challenge. I need to obtain the channel ID for a custom Slack app. To clarify, I'm not looking for the IDs of regular Slack channels, which I understand can be retrieved using the conversations.list method. Instead, I need to find the channel ID that is specific to a custom Slack app.

An example of the kind of Channel ID I'm seeking would look something like this: "D01ABCD02EF3".

Is there a way to obtain this specific type of channel ID using the Slack API? Please note that I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve manually copying the ID from the Slack team URL.